# templatetags and context['request']

Tags: wagtail

So i'm learning Wagtail and trying to understand how to generate menus. So far i've found the [bakerydemo repo](https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo) helpful. One major point of confusion for me is understanding how to use the templatetags used for menus in the bakery demo. Below is the code for the get_site_root tag ([django docs recommend that as of 1.11 that simple_tag will also work](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#s-assignment-tags) and so I changed it to that.)

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
  def get_site_root(context):
   # This returns a core.Page. The main menu needs to have 
   # the site.root_page
   #defined else will return an object attribute error ('str' object 
   #has no attribute 'get_children')
   return context['request'].site.root_page
```

No matter what I do I can't seem to get this to work. Either nothing is returned or I get various errors like the request key isn't in context or others. I looked at the [Site middleware](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailcore/middleware.py) then traced that to the site model staticmethod "find_for_request" which in turn should be calling ["get_site_for_hostname" in the sites.py](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtailcore/sites.py) . Anyways, I would love some guidance on what I am doing wrong or misunderstanding. Also, any help in understading the "wagtailthonic" way of generating menus from page hierarchies would be welcome.

Here is an image of the page and site tables.

[image: wagtail site and page tables]

Comment: Did you look at the bakerydemo fixtures https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/blob/master/bakerydemo/base/fixtures/bakerydemo.json ? 

You should probably have a corresponding Site object in the database to the url you are using to access the app.

Comment: I uploaded an image of my site and page tables. Looking at the fixtures in the bakery project, mine seems to be in order though the root_page column is now root_page_id (using wagtail 1.13.1)

```
 {
     "model": "wagtailcore.site",
     "pk": 2,
     "fields": {
     "hostname": "127.0.0.1",
     "port": 8000,
     "site_name": "Main",
     "root_page": 60,
     "is_default_site": true
     }
    },
```

Still getting no output.